# How to make elements in a row inline in IE

Tags: html, jsp

I have one row consisting of two tds. TD1 contains two texts(txt1 and txt2). txt2 in TD1 must be in line with TD2. Here's my code :

```
<tr>

        <td width="220">
        <span class="b">TB From:</span>
        <span style="position: relative; left : 20px;" id="lblTBHoriz" class="b"><br> 
        <span style="padding-left: 1.5px">  TBN:</span>
        </span>
        </td>

        <td>
        <pre></pre> 
        <input type="text" id="tBFrom"  name="tBFrom"
         value="" size="20" maxlength="16"
         onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event);"  onchange="validate(this);" > 
        </input>
        </td>

    </tr>
```

The problem is TBN: and the input box in the other td must be in line and in mozilla its working perfectly. But in IE, the input box is going up the text TBN: and getting aligned with TB From: text. What can i do to fix this one ? Kindly help .

Comment: Which version are you using of IE?

Comment: IE 7 and 8 --> that's what i am using.

Comment: You can't use tr td like this, You can adjust this to your requirement but its not proper coding

Comment: I don't see any difference in mozilla and IE-8 output. your code seems
to be fine to me

Comment: Drop the tables, use `div`tags :)

Comment: @Dolours : I see and feel what you mean. But it's kind of an eisting code and i dont have the authority to drop / chop-change existing framework. It sucks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case the `<input>` has to be at the bottom each time you can add a class to the `td` tag and add some CSS to it:

```
td.your-class
{
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

Tables are supposed to have tabular data. It's not recommended to use them for lay-out.
You could use `div`tags instead.

```
<div>TB From:</div>
<div><label>TBN:</label><input type="text" vlaue="" /></div>
```

The `div`tags you can style however you like.

Answer (score 1):

```
<tr>

        <td colspan="2" width="220">
        <span class="b">TB From:</span>
        <span style="position: relative; left : 20px;" id="lblTBHoriz" class="b"><br> 
        <span style="padding-left: 1.5px">  TBN:</span>
        </span>
        </td>

        <td colspan="2">
        <pre></pre> 

            <br/>

        <input type="text" id="tBFrom"  name="tBFrom"
         value="" size="20" maxlength="16"
         onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event);"  onchange="validate(this);" > 
        </input>
        </td>

    </tr>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dolours/zvMKH/335/